# Правомерность выражения "у нас с ним отношения"

Tags: грамотная-речь

В ходу выражение "у нас с ним отношения". Коробит, когда слышу.
Мне кажется, не хватает прилагательного: хорошие отношения, плохие, сложные, половые... А просто "отношения" — нелепость... Ваше мнение?

Answer (score 1):

Русское слово отношение, говорит Даль, это от глагола относить.

> ОТНОСИТЬ, отнести или отнесть, отнашивать что куда, кому или к кому, взяв в одном месте, перенести в другое, принести кому, доставить на себе. Отнести письмо на почту. Отнеси самовар к меднику, занеси по пути книжку к брату, да принеси от нею другую.

*Одним словом - курьерский жаргон.*

> - Что куда, к чему, приписывать, находить причину, повод, связь. Изобретенье грамоты нашей относят за тысячу лет, относят к такому-то году. Звезды ученые относят к солнцам, а планеты к землям или к мирам.

То есть слово относить в современном смысле схоже со словом классифицировать. То как, куда классифицируют тот или иной объект.

То есть отношение - это процесс классификации объектов по ряду характерных признаков.

А *у нас* ОТНОШЕНИЯ - это уже сленг и термин, потому что обрубец и перевертыш фразы. Дословный перевод термина relations, от relationship, relate(пересчёт, пересмотр, приносить назад!) + ship(доставлять, переправлять). То есть оценка глагола действия ОТНОСИТЬ, обратная связь, реакция на принесенное. В то время как ОТНОСИТЬ - это уносить, прекращать что-то нести, привязывать к чему-то другому, потому Даль дальше пишет:

> Относиться с чем, перестать носиться, возиться, нянчиться...

> Относительно, и это хорошо, небезусловно, сравнительно с худшим... *ну вы поняли...*

> Относительный, в чем есть отношенье к чему, зависимость от чего...

То есть отношение к чему-то - это "зависимость" по-русски. С точки зрения психологии, зависимые отношения - это совсем не хорошо... [Sense of "to feel connected or sympathetic to" is attested from 1950, originally in psychology jargon.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/relate?ref=etymonline_crossreference#:%7E:text=Sense%20of%20%22to%20feel%20connected%20or%20sympathetic%20to%22%20is%20attested%20from%201950%2C%20originally%20in%20psychology%20jargon.) [*sympathetic - In the anatomical sense, "subject to a common nervous influence," the word is attested from 1769,](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sympathetic#etymonline_v_30618:%7E:text=In%20the%20anatomical%20sense%2C%20%22subject%20to%20a%20common%20nervous%20influence%2C%22%20the%20word%20is%20attested%20from%201769)

А вот сленговое **ОТНОШЕНИЯ** приписывает совершенно иное значение. Потому что **это некая обратная связь**, если исходить из логики английского языка, **та выгода, которую каждый получает в зависимости от другого.** Ну и конечно, нельзя сказать "отношения" и думать что вас поймут однозначно, хотя если это уже не слово, а какой-то ЗНАК = ОТНОШЕНИЯ, то тут требовать какого-то смысла уже нет смысла...

Однако, если подобирать русское слово, то сленгизм **ОТНОШЕНИЯ** - **это** скорее подношения, от которых кто-то весьма зависит, **ПОДАЧКИ** - *то что лучше, только в отношении "чем ничего", конформизм.*

В общем да, согласен, что нужно обязательно какие отношения, и даже слово "хорошие" или "плохие" не достаточно, нужно рабочие или сексуальные(а не половые, не стоит сленгизировать дальше русский). Если рабочие - то это может значить, мы приносим пользу друг другу. А если...

Хотя, сильно лучше от этого звучать сленговое "отношения" не будет, так как это термин-урод, один из многих. Хотя, если говорить по-русски: "*мы с ним делаем друг другу подачки*" - то весьма точно может отражать текущее *скупое на любовь* положение дел с кем-то. Хотя, конечно, если это дорогие подарки, то причем тут любовь, зачем любовь, если: "лучше плакать в Porsche, чем смеяться в метро" - как это там у Даля, *относительно - это хорошо, небезусловно, сравнительно с худшим...* Ну и опять же, из уст женщины это еще может как-то звучать, а со стороны мужчины - это как?

Наверное, нужно очищать речь и мысли от сленгизмов, выражать свои мысли грамотно, можно даже просто, беря пример с Льва Николаевича, а потом может разберется, что в конечном счёте относится к себе, а что нет и как это все выглядит. Ну а внешний белый шум можно скомпенсировать только собственным верным звучанием.